# MariaDB accepts any password

Tags: password, mariadb

Running MariaDB 10.1.23-MariaDB-9+deb9u1 on Debian 9.1.
Fresh OS installation, installed MariaDB with `apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client`

Apparently MariaDB doesn't ask for a root password on install so I'm going to set it after the fact:

```
# mysql -uroot
> select user from mysql.user;
+------+
| user |
+------+
| root |
+------+
```

Ok, so root exists. Now to change its password:

```
> set password for 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('P@ssw0rd');
> flush privileges;
> exit
```

Did it work?

```
# mysql -uroot -pblabla
MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Setting the password went ok but why is MariaDB accepting any random password and even an empty one?

This installation doesn't accept ALTER USER statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63605/discussion-between-forkbeard-and-derobert).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer: https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/:

> Apparently the mysql-server installation on 16.04 (or any 5.7
>   installation?) allows root access not through password, but through
>   the auth_socket plugin. Running sudo mysql -u root (n.b. w/o a
>   password) will give you mysql console whereas running the command as
>   non-root prompts you for a password.
>
> It would seem that changing the password doesn't make much of a
>   difference since the auth backend doesn't even check for a password.

To disable this auth_socket plugin, on the mysql prompt do

```
update mysql.user set plugin=null where user='root';
flush privileges;
```

This makes MariaDB also ask a password for [Linux] root.

Thanks jesse-b and derobert for the in-depth discussion and your answers.

Comment: this is the best answer WORKING i found, without this command, mariadb will not work if you use phpmyadmin !

Comment: in mariadb-server 10.3 plugin cannot be null so just set it to empty string

Answer (score 1):

also check your my.cnf if it has "skip-grant-tables" if yes, remove it.